# Unit Test return early if statement

Tags: ios, objective-c, unit-testing

I have this code

```
- (BOOL)shouldStartWithOptions:(Options *)options
{
    if (...) {
        return NO;
    }

    if (...) {
        return NO;
    }

    if (...) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (void)startWithOptions:(Options *)options
{
    if ([self shouldStartWithOptions:options]) {
        return;
    }

    [self startProductA];
    [self startProductB];
    [self startProductC];
    // and do other stuffs
}
```

How would I unit test the fact that when I call `myMethod` and that `shouldReturn` returns YES, then I return early.

One idea is to expect a method `anotherMethod` not to be executed but I don't think this would be a good idea since the test could remain green if the code is updates to the following

```
- (void)myMethod
{
    [self shouldReturn];
}
```

**Do you have other ideas?**

Comment: I would be more concerned with testing that your method does what it is supposed to do, i.e. if its like `createFileIfPermitted`, then you could test the logic when you do and do not have permissions, and semantically the `shouldReturn` would mean you don't. I think more context is needed about what your method should be doing.

Comment: I agree with C.B. here. Test the external interface of your system, not the internal implementation

Comment: I edited the code. So you mean you would create two unit tests where shouldStartWithOptions: return either YES or NO and make sure that in the first case the three product are started and in the second case that none of the product are started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How would I unit test ...

That entirely depends on what the side-effects of that method are.  Presumably these statements are true:

- When `self shouldStartWithOptions:` is false, the method produces some observable side-effect in the state of the system.
- When `self shouldStartWithOptions:` is true, the method does not produce that side-effect.

So the way you'd test your "early return" is simply by asserting whether or not the intended side effect(s) of the method is/are present after it executes.

> but I don't think this would be a good idea since the test could remain green if the code is updates to the following ...

The "early return" test shouldn't remain green in that case.  Consider two tests:

1. Given one precondition, a side-effect is observed.
2. Given another precondition, a side-effect is *not* observed.  (Explicitly not observed, as in the *lack* of the side-effect is observed.)

If you remove the conditional from the method, the second test should fail because the side-effect would always be observed.

---

Unit testing is all about observing and validating the effects of the code on the system.  Whether those effects are returned values, or invocations on supplied mocks, or some other altered state in the system... It's always the same logic:

- Arrange - Define the known preconditions of the system
- Act - Execute the code being tested
- Assert - Validate that the expected effect on the system is observed

This has little to do with the implementation of the method itself and everything to do with the external expectations of what that method is meant to do.

Comment: Thanks for the explicit answer.

Comment: What if it's a memory consumption/performance concern? Of course, still talking about unit tests, benchmarks could be an option.